# Check for Apache state in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, java, apache-http-server, httpd

Hi i have a java application that starts/stops/restart Apache and it should also check for its status, so i have looked how checking for status of apache and it appears that you have to check for the state of the service, problem is that when i use

```
apachectl start
```

the service httpd is still not started, is that normal ?

i check for the service state by doing

```
service httpd status
```

.

```
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]# service httpd status
httpd is stopped
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]# /apps/apache/2.4.4/bin/apachectl start
httpd (pid 20502) already running
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]# service httpd status
httpd is stopped
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]# /apps/apache/2.4.4/bin/apachectl stop
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]# service httpd status
httpd is stopped
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]# /apps/apache/2.4.4/bin/apachectl start
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]# service httpd status
httpd is stopped
[root@lxrdcpsm ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below commands in your terminal..

```
[root@localhost ~]# service httpd start
```

OR

```
 [root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

After starting it will be running until the system is shut down. While checking status you will get output something like this.

```
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd status
httpd (pid  2107) is running...
```

If you want to start this service automatically on system boot use the below command.

```
[root@localhost ~]#chkconfig --level 3 httpd on
```

Where 3 is your current runlevel.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't started because you didn't start it.

Nowadays the new utility responsible for managing services is `systemctl` and the command to start Apache is

```
systemctl start httpd
```

However, one can keep on using the old terminology: `service httpd start`

Assuming that you want it to start with the system, use the following command:

```
chkconfig httpd on
```